Builtin Webcam not working
iamjedi322@iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748:/$ uname -a
Linux iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
iamjedi322@iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748:/$ locate video0
/dev/video0
iamjedi322@iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748:/$ ls -l /dev/video0
ls: cannot access '/dev/video0': No such file or directory
iamjedi322@iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Synaptics RMI4 Touch Sensor (rmi4:rmi4-00.fn54):
    /dev/v4l-touch0

Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
Please Assist.

Install cheese. sudo apt install cheese. Does it not see any webcam?

I have cheese installed. It didn't see any webcam. The reason I need it is for a proctoring web application for a test I'm going to take. It was working, and then I moved the laptop screen more towards me and it hasn't been working since. It could be a hardware issue. I'm at work right now so I can't work on it.
